# 'sqlcmd' is not recognized at CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLoginSqlCmd step

Tags: sql-database, installation, sitecore-install-framework

I'm trying to install **Sitecore 9 Update 1 XP0 topology** and everything looks great until the step

> **CreateShardApplicationDatabaseServerLoginSqlCmd**

[image]

The server I am running the installation was already used to install XP1 topology, and everything worked just fine.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right after post my question, realized that sqlcmd was not installed at the server - which is weird, because XP1 topology didn't require at all!

In my case, I had to download and install

- [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420)
- [Microsoft Command Line Utilities 13 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52680)

Once I got both installed, it was just a matter to re-run the XP0.

Comment: Unfortunately this was missed off the docs for update 1.  We're aiming to have this corrected soon.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you, Vinicius. To add to the correct answer, after downloading the two utilities from your answer, my problem was not resolved.

I encountered into the same issue when running Sitecore installation using SIF on staging environment where SQL server was not added to environment variables.
When running the SIF on dev/staging/prod environments where SQL server management studio is not installed, after installing the 2 utilities, we need to make sure that environment System variable `Path` should contain `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn` which is a location of "SQLCMD.EXE"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Vinicius answer and Rama suggestion.

If it still does not work Restart would help. It worked for me after a restart.