# Sitecore 9.3 XP0 installation error - XConnectXP0_CleanShards

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I have already installed prerequisites but getting below error.
**Some details:**

- SQL Server version - 2017
- Sitecore version - 9.3
- Onprem

**Error:**

```
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------- XConnectXP0_CleanShards : Command -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The 
term 'd:\xxx\xconnect\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\resourcefiles\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:80 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
 
[TIME] 00:03:23
Invoke-CommandTask : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The term 
'd:\xxx\xconnect\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:47
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-CommandTask], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Invoke-CommandTask
```

Comment: Follow this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/sqlcmd-is-not-recognized-at-createshardapplicationdatabaseserverloginsqlcmd-st

Comment: That is a different error related to "SQLCMD". Please the check the error i added. 
I already checked before creating this question. I didn't find a similar question.